# How find this integral $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log{\cos^2{x}}}{1+e^{2x}}dx$

Tags: integration

find the value
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\log{\cos^2{x}}}{1+e^{2x}}dx$$

My try: let $$e^{2x}=u\Longrightarrow x=\dfrac{1}{2}\log{u}$$

then
$$I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\log{(\cos^2{(\dfrac{1}{2}\log{u})})}}{2u(1+u)}du$$

then I can't.Thank you

Answer (score 14):

Referring to the identity

$$ \log|\cos x| = - \log 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \cos (2nx) $$

(which can be easily obtained by considering the real part of $\log (1 + e^{2ix})$), we find that

\begin{align*}
I&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{1+e^{2x}} \left\{ - \log 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \cos (2nx) \right\} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+e^{x}} \left\{ - \log 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \cos (nx) \right\} \, dx \quad (2x \mapsto x) \\
&= - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log 2}{1+e^{x}} \, dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} \left\{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{m-1}e^{-mx} \right\} \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \cos (nx) \right\} \, dx \\
&= -\log^{2} 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos (nx) e^{-mx} \, dx \\
&= -\log^{2} 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{n} \frac{m}{m^{2} + n^{2}} \\
&=: -\log^{2} 2 + S.
\end{align*}

Now let us consider the sum $S$. Interchanging the role of $m$ and $n$, we have

$$ S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{m} \frac{n}{m^{2} + n^{2}}. $$

Averaging,

$$ S
= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{m}{n} + \frac{n}{m} \right) \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{m^{2} + n^{2}}
= \frac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \right)^{2}
= \frac{1}{2}\log^{2} 2. $$

Therefore the answer is

$$ I = -\frac{1}{2}\log^{2} 2. $$

Comment: It's nice,Thank you +1

Comment: You wrote "which can be easily obtained by considering the real part of $log(1+e2ix)$ " . I did that and found this. 
$$log(1+cos2x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}cos(2nx)$$ 
So we have
$$log(1+cos2x)=log(1+cos^{2}x-sin^{2}x)=log(2cos^{2}x)=log2+2log\mid cosx\mid $$
By that we obtain
$$log\mid cosx\mid =\frac{1}{2}(-log2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}cos(2nx))$$
But you didn't wrote $1/2$ there. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @esege One observation is that $$\log \left| 2 \cos x \right| = \log \left| e^{ix} + e^{-ix} \right| = \log \left| 1 + e^{2ix} \right| = \Re \log (1 + e^{2ix}). $$ The next observation is the Taylor series of the logarithm. You can deduce the identity by combining these observations.